# Add image to top left of screen (FLUTTER SCROLL)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver

So I have a pretty simple issue. I have an image. Lets say its 'assets/images/user.png'. I want that image to appear in the top left of the app (In the middle of the white circle). When the user scrolls downward, the title, and description both disappear and then the Go Premium button get pinned to the top. I want a user png to appear in the TOP LEFT corner in the MIDDlE of the white circle, and then when the user scrolls down, I want the user png to go down a bit and position itself to the left of the Go Premium button, in the small gap. I want this to work for different phones too, so hardcoding is allowed IF it would work for a smaller phone. Thanks!
Here is an image of my app before scroll: [image]
Here is one after scroll: [image]

```
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor:
                    const Color.fromARGB(12, 14, 13, 3).withOpacity(1),
                centerTitle: false,
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: size.width * .7,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0)),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Go Premium!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                pinned: true,
                expandedHeight: 165,
                titleSpacing: 15,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                  background: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Positioned(
                        top: -size.width * .08,
                        left: -size.width * .08,
                        child: Transform.translate(
                          offset: const Offset(-30, -30),
                          child: const CircleButton(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        left: size.width * .2,
                        top: size.height * .09,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            const Text('JustLift',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color:
                                        Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 250, 250),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 50)),
                            Text(
                              element,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 158, 154, 154),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: You can use `SliverPersistentHeader`

Comment: I already tried that, but all that happened was that there were two headers instead of one. So the image was in one header, and when that header collapsed there was another header that also had to collapse. I am very confused on why this isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lerp method from `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`. Try to play with widget

```dart
class CustomSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate
    extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  CustomSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate({required this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final t = shrinkOffset / maxExtent;
    final avatarSize = lerpDouble(100, 48, t);
    return Material(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: lerpDouble(maxExtent / 2, -60, t),
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Text(
              'Hello',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: lerpDouble(-20, 0, t),
            left: lerpDouble(-20, 4, t),
            child: Container(
              width: avatarSize,
              height: avatarSize,
              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                shape: CircleBorder(),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 8,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: onTap,
                child: Text('Button'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 200;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And use like

```dart
return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: CustomSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate(
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 2222,
      ),
    )
  ],
));
```

If you need more accuracy on overlapping, You can use [CompositedTransformTarget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformTarget-class.html)